# Не выделяется элемент BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, view

Имеется BottomNavigationView и на нём 4 элемента.
Когда на BottomNavigationView не висит OnNavigationSelectedListener все элементы при клике на них выделяются, а когда слушатель есть, не выделяются. Чем можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что в слушателе в конце надо возвращать значение true.
Всё разрешилось :)